# How to fetch multi-dimensional mix array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have this array stored in a variable :-

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
          [date] => 06/01/2016 - 06/30/2016 
          [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 34 [2] => 2 [3] => 55 ) 
          [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 55 [2] => 55 [3] => 100 ) 
          [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 60 [2] => 100 [3] => 500 ) 
  ) 
)
```

here is my code to print it :

```
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    foreach($table as $tier)
    {
        echo $tier[0]."<br>";
        echo $tier[1]."<br>";
        echo $tier[2]."<br>";
        echo $tier[3]."<br>";
    }
}
```

This is what it's printing:

```
0
6
/
0
1
34
2
55
2
55
55
100
3
60
100
500
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
1
34
2
55
2
55
55
100
3
60
100
500
```

How can I  get the desired result using `foreach()`?

Comment: You just need to exclude the `date` key when looping don't you?

Comment: Let me know if my answer made everything work perfectly.

Comment: Please don't do that. It's all well and good to ask people to accept answers, but don't try pushing people into accepting your own...

Comment: Sir, i got downvote, I don't know why.

Comment: @RivnatNasah Frankly, I don't know either (though personally I would have laid it out differently and kept it as close to the original as possible).

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `date` field is interpreted as a tier. Skip non-numeric tiers like this:

```
foreach ($tables as $table)
{
    foreach ($table as $index => $tier)
    {
       if (!is_numeric($index))
           continue;

        echo $tier[0]."<br>";
        echo $tier[1]."<br>";
        echo $tier[2]."<br>";
        echo $tier[3]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Here's an example of this working:

```
php > $tables = array(0 => array('date' => '06/01/2016 - 06/30/2016', 0 => array(1, 34, 2, 55), 1 => array(2, 55, 55, 100), 2 => array(3, 60, 100, 500)));

php > foreach ($tables as $table)
php > {
php {     foreach ($table as $index => $tier)
php {     {
php {        if (!is_numeric($index))
php {            continue;
php {
php {         echo $tier[0]."<br>";
php {         echo $tier[1]."<br>";
php {         echo $tier[2]."<br>";
php {         echo $tier[3]."<br>";
php {     }
php { }
1<br>34<br>2<br>55<br>2<br>55<br>55<br>100<br>3<br>60<br>100<br>500<br>
php >
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Excluding the date suggested by @Jon Stirling.

```
foreach($tables as $table){
    foreach($table as $k => $tier){
        if($k !== 'date')
            echo $tier[0]."<br/>".$tier[1]."<br/>".$tier[2]."<br/>".$tier[3]."<br/>";
    }
}
```

New version is here, also the previous one works well after adding `!==` in `if` condition.

```
$tables = array(
            array ( 
              'date' => "06/01/2016 - 06/30/2016",
              array ( 1, 34, 2, 55 ),
              array ( 2, 55, 55, 100 ), 
              array ( 3, 60, 100, 500 )
            )
        );
foreach($tables as $table){
    foreach($table as $k => $tier){
        if(!is_array($tier))
            continue;
        foreach($tier as $val)
            echo $val."\n";
    }
}
```

Updated with question updated.

Comment: Your code is not working , It's displaying 
2
55
55
100
3
60
100

500

Comment: @Sumit Bhatia, use `if ($k !== 'date')`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your array have only 0 index ,so directly call that array here and pass array key `date`

> use **!==** when compare "date"
>
> don't use **!=** ,it will be invalid because "date" will be convert to int `0` so will be equal in "date" and 0

```
foreach ($table[0] as $k=>$tier) {
    if($k !== 'date'){
        echo $tier[0]."<br>";
        echo $tier[1]."<br>";
        echo $tier[2]."<br>";
        echo $tier[3]."<br>";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update @RivnatNasah answer

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    foreach ($table as $key => $values){
        if ($key !== 'date') {
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                echo $value . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    foreach($table as $key => $tier)
    {
        if ($key !== 'date')
        {
            echo $tier[0]."<br>";
            echo $tier[1]."<br>";
            echo $tier[2]."<br>";
            echo $tier[3]."<br>";
       }
    }
}
```

You were really close with your code.

Comment: I downvoted because for the OPs question, this is wrong.

Comment: @Webeng Read the question. Read the other answers.

Comment: @Paul Nope. `$table` is an array.

Comment: @Webeng your check should be inside the second foreach loop.

Comment: @Webeng, I agree with @Jon Stirling: `$key` of `$tables` is 0, `$table` is array.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you, you were correct. I have deleted all my comments

Comment: @RivnatNasah thank you for your feedback, I have fixed my answer.

Comment: @Paul thank you for the feedback paul, I have fixed my answer